# Why is my else statement run in this piece of node code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm doing the learnyounode exercises. In this function, I list a directory and filter files by extension. As I understand, if I provide an invalid directory name, it should go into the `if` clause and exit. But instead, it goes to the if clause and then complains about something in the `else` clause.

Module:

```
module.exports = function (path, ext, callb) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var elems = [];
    var r = new RegExp("\\." + ext);
    fs.readdir(path, function (err, list) {
        console.log(err); // this runs, it's an object like { [Error: ENOENT, scandir '/Users/JohnnyLee/baobabf/
        console.log(list); // this also runs, it's undefined
        if (err) {
            console.log("ERR!!!"); // this ran!
            return callb(err);
        } else {
            console.log("NO ERRR!!!"); // this didn't run :/
            list.forEach(function (i) { // this crashes?
                if (i.match(r)) {
                    elems.push(i);
                }
            });
            return callb(err, elems);
        }
        console.log(list);
    });
};
```

Executable:

```
var mymod = require('./p06-1');
var filename = process.argv[2]
var extension = process.argv[3]

if (filename && extension) {
    mymod(filename, extension, function (err, list) {
        list.forEach(function (i) {
            console.log(i);
        });
    })
}
```

The output:

```
triton:learnnode JohnnyLee$ node p06-2.js doesntexist txt
{ [Error: ENOENT, scandir 'doesntexist'] errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', path: 'doesntexist' }
undefined
ERR!!!
/Users/JohnnyLee/learnnode/p06-2.js:7
        list.forEach(function (i) {
            ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at /Users/JohnnyLee/learnnode/p06-2.js:7:13
    at /Users/JohnnyLee/learnnode/p06-1.js:11:20
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
triton:learnnode JohnnyLee$
```

What did I miss :(?

Answer (score 4):

You call it with:

```
mymod(filename, extension, function (err, list) {
    list.forEach(function (i) {
        console.log(i);
    });
})
```

It is the `list.forEach` in there that errors.  Look at the filename/line number for the error.  This is because you call `callb(err)` in the module, but you don't check for an error before assuming there's a `list` to work with.

Comment: Thanks! >.< Maybe I've had a bad day not to realize.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the error stack properly, it's loud and clear :)

As for your question of what you've missed,

Add an error check statement to handle error.
Modify `mymod` call as shown below,

```
if (filename && extension) {
    mymod(filename, extension, function (err, list) {
       if(err){
               //do something with error
          }else{
        list.forEach(function (i) {
            console.log(i);
                 }
        });
    })
}
```